# how to dynamically add rows to table on pressing submit on form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need help creating the part where the rows are automatically added when the user press submit button. Right now there are 4 fields and a submit button. Below that there is a table which shows all the data. so when someone enters the data in the text field and presses submit it should store that data into 'genData' and after that, it should create a new row in the table and people should be able to see the new data it should right under the current data that's already displayed.

```
const genData = [
{ firstName: "foo", lastName: "boo", type: "male", email: "fooboo@gmail.com"}

];

class Stepper extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <TextField
      hintText="First Name"
    />
    <TextField
      hintText="Last Name"
    />
    <TextField
      hintText="Type"
    />
    <TextField
      hintText="Email"
    />
    <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true}/>

    <Table>
<TableHeader>
  <TableRow>
    <TableHeaderColumn>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Type</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
<TableBody>
  {genData.map( (row) => (
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>{row.firstName}</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>{row.lastName}</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>{row.email}</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
</Table>

  </div>
);
}
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read any (from many) todo examples for react, since they all have functionality you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** Store the data in state of `Stepper`, so that whenever you will add new entry in that it will automatically re-render the table.

**2.** Define a `onTouchTap` event with `RaisedButton` button and on click of that push the new data in state variable.

**3.** Either you have to use `ref` for `uncontrolled component` or define a `state` variable for each input field, to get the input field values inside submit function.

**4.** Assign unique key to each element when creating by loop.

Full Code:

```
class Stepper extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      genData : [
          {
            firstName: "foo", 
            lastName: "boo", 
            type: "male", 
            email: "fooboo@gmail.com"
          }
      ]
    }
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  _handleSubmit(){
    let genData = this.state.genData.slice();
    genData.push({
      firstName: this.fName.props.value, 
      lastName: this.lName.props.value, 
      type: this.type.props.value, 
      email: this.email.props.value
    });
    this.setState({ genData })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          ref={el => this.fName = el}
          hintText="First Name"
        />
        <TextField
          ref={el => this.lName = el}
          hintText="Last Name"
        />
        <TextField
          ref={el => this.type = el}
          hintText="Type"
        />
        <TextField
          ref={el => this.email = el}
          hintText="Email"
        />
        <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this._handleSubmit} label="Submit" primary={true}/>

        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Type</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.genData.map( (row, i) => (
              <TableRow key={i}>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.firstName}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.lastName}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.email}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Use this code for controlled component:

```
class Stepper extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      type: '',
      email: '',
      genData : [
          {
            firstName: "foo", 
            lastName: "boo", 
            type: "male", 
            email: "fooboo@gmail.com"
          }
      ]
    }
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  _handleSubmit(){
    let genData = this.state.genData.slice();
    genData.push({
      firstName: this.state.fName, 
      lastName: this.state.lName, 
      type: this.state.type,
      email: this.state.email
    });
    this.setState({ 
      genData,
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      type: '',
      email: '' 
    })
  }

  onChange(fieldName, value){
    this.setState({
      [fieldName]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          value={this.state.fName}
          onChange={(e,value) => this.onChange('fName', value)}
          hintText="First Name"
        />
        <TextField
          value={this.state.lName}
          onChange={(e,value) => this.onChange('lName', value)}
          hintText="Last Name"
        />
        <TextField
          value={this.state.type}
          onChange={(e,value) => this.onChange('type', value)}
          hintText="Type"
        />
        <TextField
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={(e,value) => this.onChange('email', value)}
          hintText="Email"
        />
        <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this._handleSubmit} label="Submit" primary={true}/>

        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Type</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.genData.map( (row, i) => (
              <TableRow key={i}>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.firstName}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.lastName}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.email}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when I press submit it doesn't re-render and update the table. It doesn't do anything

Comment: @JohnBerry sorry, there was a typo in handlesubmit function in like line: `let genData = this.state.slice();` check the updated code specially `handlesubmit` function use this line: `let genData = this.state.genData.slice();` it will work.

Comment: that fixed the error but the problem is it creates a blank line in the table it doesn't take the data from the field and put it in the table row

Comment: put `console.log(this.fName.value, this.lName.value, this.type.value)` inside handleSubmit function and let me know the output.

Comment: it still comes blank

Comment: undefined undefined undefined

Comment: @JohnBerry got it, it's a `material ui` component so `ref` will have the reference of the wrapper. we need to use `this.fName.props.value` check the updated `handlesubmit` function it will work :)

Comment: it still doesnt :(

Comment: i tried and it's working for me, can you show the code on pastebin that you are using ? as well as not tell me the output of `console.log(this.fName.props.value, this.lName.props.value);`

Comment: don't worry if this part will not work, i will give you a new code with controlled component :)

Comment: console.log shows undefined undefined, but the table still creats a new blank line. Are there any libraries that i have to add in addition to what i alredy have is import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import from 'material-ui/Table';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

Comment: ohk wait 5 mins, writing it by another way. no you don't need to include any other lib for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Event Listener/Handler on the button, to do something when it is clicked. In React components you usually pass the function to get called via the `onClick` prop but it depends on the component.

```
<RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true} onClick={(e) => doSomething(); } />
```

`<RaisedButton />` also has a `onTouchTap` property for touch input, you may want to check that (documentation [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button))

To get the new data you need to get the values of all your `<TextField />` components and push them into the `genData` array. I also recommend this array to be an internal [state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and update it using `this.setState()`.